# Strip specific characters and replaced with word

Tags: javascript

**If I have this string:**

```
This string should @[1234] by another word
```

I want to replace to remove @ [ ] and replace 1234 with 'test' word for example so the result is:

```
This string should test by another word
```

Is there any way to do this with js?

Comment: Can you show us both an example of a desired input output, as well as the code you have tried?

Comment: *Is there any way to do this with js?* Yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression to repalce your @[XXX] by test with the following code :

```js
var string = "This string should @[1234] by another word";
console.log(string.replace(/@\[[0-9]+\]/gi, "test"));
```

Comment: My 50 cents, here is an explanation about the regex used: https://regex101.com/r/l6KohQ/1/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to define a mapping from ids to replacements first.

Then you use `string.replace(regex, callback)` with a regex that matches `@[1234]` or any other id within the brackets and captures the id within a capture group.

Finally, you provide a callback which receives the value of the capture group as the second parameter and performs the replacement according to your mapping:

```js
const input = 'This string should @[1234] by another word';
const replacements = {'1234': 'test'}; 
const output = input.replace(/@\[(\d+)\]/g, (match, id) => replacements[id]);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have multiple texts to replace? If so, you can use the String.replace function with a callback, which provides the replacement value. Something like this:

```js
var repls = {
  "1234": "test"
};

var text = "This string should @[1234] by another word";

var result = text.replace(/@\[([0-9]+)\]/g, function(entireMatch, key) {
    return repls[key];
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that doesn't use regular expressions, just `split()` and `join()`, and with strings as delimiters.

```js
str='This string should @[1234] by another word';
console.log(str.split('@[1234]').join('test'));
```